# Using string resources from UserControl resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to add string resources to my UserControl. I have created a new UserControl and when I try to edit the automatically created mycontrol.resx file I'm met with this message:

> You are trying to edit a resource file that is a poart of another project item (such as a form or a control). Editing this item could corrupt the project item, and you will have to recover it by hand. In addition, changes made to this resource file may be lost if further chagnes are made to the project item.
>   Do you really want to edit this file?

If I accept and continue, I can't access the strings through mycontrol.MyString unless I change the resource file access modifier to public (default is "no code generation") but then the project doesn't compile and shows these errors:

> Missing partial modifier on declaration of type mycontrol; another partial declaration of this type exists
>   Type mycontrol already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types.

Thanks

Comment: The `UserControl.resx` file is for design-time/controls-related resources (e.g., controls' texts, locations, etc.). You shouldn't use it to add more strings. First, change the `Language` property of the UserControl and start making design-time changes to it and you'll see those changes appear under `UserControl.lng.resx`. Then, to add other strings that are not related to the controls, you should create a new resource file (one for each language) and your strings there. You could split them into multiple files if you want.

Comment: You should give [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager) a try though. It will make your life so much easier.